# HttpWebRequest.Accept in java/Android

Tags: java, android, .net

I'm doing an application that performs a REST web service query.
I need to set the following headers:

```
application / vnd.sdmx.structure + xml; version = 2.0
```

in:

```
webRequest.Accept
```

but **webRequest.Accept** is a property of .NET how can I set this in Android / Java?

I tried doing this:

```
getRequest.setHeader("webRequest.Accept",
                                "application/vnd.sdmx.structure+xml;version=2.0");
```

but don't work.

Comment: Actually, the header you really want to set is `Accept`

Comment: I tried this but the server I always answer the same thing, as if I had set.

Comment: webRequest.Accept modifies the header Accept. just go getRequest.setHeader('Accept", application/vnd.sdmx.structure+xml;version=2.0");

Comment: I tried but it does not work.

Comment: Well, then the problem might be something else

Comment: OK I wanted to be sure it was done this way. probably depends on the need, thank you.